# How to pass a non-string value between two JSR223 (groovy) samplers in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I need to pass a value from one JSR223 sampler (groovy) to another one within the same Thread group. For now I use a User Parameter (`vars.put(...), vars.get(...)`) but it has a disadvantage that extra conversions to and from string are required to pass non-string data. Is there a way to pass an object (e.g. Integer or Date) between two groovy samplers in JMeter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide:

> vars
>
> vars is the most frequently used component which represents JMeter Variables. It’s an instance of [org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class and provides read/write access to current variables, capable of enumerating/changing existing, creating new ones and obtaining nested properties.

If you look into JMeterVariables class JavaDoc by following above link you'll be able to see [putObject(String key, Object value)](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method which seems to be what you're looking for.

So in the first sampler:

```
Date now = new Date();
vars.putObject("now", now):
```

And in the second sampler:

```
Date then = vars.getObject("now");
```

Alternatively you can use `props.put(String, Object)` and `props.get(String, Object)` - in that case you will be able to access the values from different Thread Groups.

Comment: Indeed, I've overlooked get/putObject. Excellent answer, 100% useful. I tick it as the solution.